# need to assign a ticket in round robin with keeping last assigned and member on leave keeping in calculation

Tags: excel, vba, round-robin

I have four members A,B,C,D in my team (which may vary to 5-6),
to whom I need to assign ticket in round robin,
my last assigned was B and today round robin should start from C, but if C is on leave today then it should not assign to C and check if D is present or not if D is also not present then it should check if A is present or not, if A is present then it will assign today's first ticket to A.

Comment: Are you having a *specific* problem with this?  What is that exactly?

Comment: I can see in many teams in my organization , tickets are being assigned manually, If some how i am able to make above logic I can eliminate manual tasks